# how to create a setup file for c# application that is connected to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, installation

I created a desktop application using c# and MySQL database , now I’m trying to create the setup for my application i tried to use intallshield , on my computer the application worked normally , but when using it on another computer ( that doesn't have MySQL installed on it ) , the application doesn't work, 
so how can create the setup that contains my database.

Comment: Are you trying to install the MySQL server software in your installer? (That's a significant pain in the neck to get right.) Or are you hoping for an installer that will help the user construct a connection string to a MySQL instance that's already up and running?

Comment: actually ! the user of the application doesn't have mysql installed on his machine , so wht should i do !

Comment: Database software like MySQL works best when it runs on a server shared by multiple users of an application. If you are looking for a single-user local DBMS, you may be better off with SQL server express or SQLite. Both are free-to-redistribute, and both are *much* easier to install than a MySQL server instance.